# Correct way to calculate correlations between factors

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, factor-analysis

What is the correct way to calculate correlations between factors of FA model in python? I tried this approach (calculated it on factor scores of my dataframe objects) on FA without rotation or with varimax (wanted to calc correlations when between factors extracted by oblique rotation but firstly decided to check calculation method on orthogonal rotation), for sklearn.decomposition.FactorAnalysis this shows correct result (almost diagonal matrix) but for factor_analyzer.FactorAnalyzer matrix substantially differs from diagonal: [image: here] - what's the reason? Don't think factor_analyzer.FactorAnalyzer has error on it, so what's the right way to calculate correlations (and why approach I've applied shows correct result for sklearn.decomposition.FactorAnalysis)?

```
def get_correlations_between_factors(dataframe, fa_model):
    import pandas as pd

    fa_model.fit(dataframe)
    result = fa_model.transform(dataframe)
    return pd.DataFrame(result).corr()
```

Answer (score 0):

With an orthogonal rotation (or no rotation at all), `FactorAnalyzer` does not provide the factor correlation matrix, since it is just an identity matrix. With oblique rotations, you can use the `phi_` attribute to get the factor correlation matrix.

The `FactorAnalyzer` package works the same way as R's `psych` package. For example,

```
library(tidyverse)
library(psych)

data(bfi)
bfi_subset = bfi %>% select(matches('^A[1-5]|^N'))
bfi_subset = bfi_subset %>% 
   mutate_all(~ifelse(is.na(.), median(., na.rm = TRUE), .))

model = fa(bfi_subset, 4, rotate = 'varimax')
print(model$Phi)
print(round(cor(model$scores), 3))
```

Results in the following:

```
NULL
       MR2    MR1    MR3    MR4
MR2  1.000 -0.044 -0.004 -0.283
MR1 -0.044  1.000  0.297 -0.014
MR3 -0.004  0.297  1.000  0.116
MR4 -0.283 -0.014  0.116  1.000
```

Taking the correlations of the factor scores won't necessarily work the way you seem to expect. For example,

```
round(cor(model1$scores), 3)
```

Outputs the following:

```
    MR2 MR1 MR3 MR4
MR2 1.000   -0.044  -0.004  -0.283
MR1 -0.044  1.000   0.297   -0.014
MR3 -0.004  0.297   1.000   0.116
MR4 -0.283  -0.014  0.116   1.000
```

If you would like to prove to yourself that the factors are indeed orthogonal (uncorrelated), you can do the following in `FactorAnalyzer`:

```
fa = FactorAnalyzer(n_factors=4, rotation='varimax')
fa.fit(df_sub)
th = fa.rotation_matrix_
print(pd.DataFrame(th.T.dot(th)).round(2))
```

Which outputs the following:

```
     0    1    2    3
0  1.0  0.0 -0.0 -0.0
1  0.0  1.0  0.0 -0.0
2 -0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
3 -0.0 -0.0  0.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to add here: When you use the `transform()` method, you're calculating the factor scores. There are different ways to do that. `FactorAnalyzer` implements the Thurstone method, but there are other methods that will preserve the underlying correlations, such as the "ten Berge" method.

If this is something you'd like us to implement in `FactorAnalyzer`, please feel free file an issue. Here's a rough implementation:

```
import warnings
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale


def ten_berge(X, loadings, phi=None):
    """
    Estimate factor scores using the "ten Berge" method.

    Parameters
    ----------
    X : array-like
        The data set
    loadings : array-like
        The loadings matrix

    Reference
    ----------
    https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379597100076
    """
    # get the number of factors from the loadings
    n_factors = loadings.shape[1]
    corr = np.corrcoef(X, rowvar=False)
    # if `phi` is None, create a diagonal matrix
    phi = np.diag(np.ones(n_factors)) if phi is None else phi
    # calculate intermediate metrics
    load = loadings.dot(matrix_sqrt(phi))
    corr_inv = inv_matrix_sqrt(corr)
    temp = corr_inv.dot(load)\
                   .dot(inv_matrix_sqrt(load.T.dot(np.linalg.inv(corr))
                                              .dot(load)))
    # calcualte weights
    weights = corr_inv.dot(temp)\
                      .dot(matrix_sqrt(phi))
    # calculate scores, given weights
    scores = scale(X).dot(weights)
    return scores


def matrix_sqrt(x):
    """
    Compute the square root of the eigen values (eVal),
    and then take $eVec * diag(eVals^0.5) * eVec^T$
    """
    evals, evecs = np.linalg.eig(x)
    evals[evals < 0] = np.finfo(float).eps
    sqrt_evals = np.sqrt(evals)
    return evecs.dot(np.diag(sqrt_evals)).dot(evecs.T)


def inv_matrix_sqrt(x):
    """
    Compute the inverse square root of the eigen values (eVal),
    and then take $eVec * diag(1 / eVals^0.5) * eVec^T$
    """
    evals, evecs = np.linalg.eig(x)
    if np.iscomplex(evals).any():
        warnings.warn('Complex eigen values detected; results are suspect.')
        return x
    evals[evals < np.finfo(float).eps] = 100 * np.finfo(float).eps
    inv_sqrt_evals =  1 / np.sqrt(evals)
    return evecs.dot(np.diag(inv_sqrt_evals)).dot(evecs.T)

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vincentarelbundock/Rdatasets/master/csv/psych/bfi.csv')
df = df.filter(regex='^A[1-5]|^N').copy()
df = df.fillna(df.median(0))

fa = FactorAnalyzer(n_factors=5, rotation=None).fit(df)
pd.DataFrame(ten_berge(df, fa.loadings_)).corr().round(3)
```

Comment: No, personally me don't need any addings, just got confused because of my misunderstanding (as understood from your answers) of difference between factor scores and inner structure of fa, rotation matrix and so on (didn't read theory well, will try to figure out once more with a help of your code)